# Write a program that prints the integers from 1 to 100 (inclusive) in one line of code, however

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am new to python and would like to write a program that prints the integers from 1 to 100 (inclusive) in **1 line** using python, however:

- For multiples of three, print `shell` (instead of the number)
- For multiples of five, print `fish` (instead of the number)
- For multiples of both three and five , print `shellfish` (instead of the number)

I can do this but not in one line of code unfortunately:

```
 for i in xrange(1, 101):
    if i % 15 == 0:
        print "shellfish"
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        print "shell"
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        print "fish"
    else:
        print i
```

How can make this source code into one line?

Comment: You can use semicolon `;` if you want multiple statements on one line. So you could theoretically write a whole program on one line. Although, consider not using one-liners if they make the program harder to read. What you currently have is very readable and more understandable then an equivalent one-liner.

Comment: This would fit perfectly at tips tag on [PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want the *source code* to be in one line, or the *output* of the script to be on a single line?

Comment: Source code. I know how to make it print on one line I'm not that new :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert your attempt into 1 line you could make use of `*` which is the repetition operator in python:

```
for i in xrange(1,101): print("shell"*(i%3==0) + "fish"*(i%5==0) or i)
```

Comment: The question looks like homework, so it might have been better to answer with a suggestion instead than with an answer ready to be copied...

Comment: I understand but it looks like OP figured out the hard part (the stuff with  modulo) and gave a nice attempt.

Answer (score 1):

With the conditional expression: `true_value if cond else false_value` we get this - a little bit boring - solution:

```
for i in xrange(1, 101): print (i if i % 5 else "fish") if i % 3 else ("shell" if i % 5 else "shellfish")
```